# ヘッドレスChromeで Yahoo! JAPAN スクリーンキャプチャを取得すると一部分だけ、記事を取得できませんでした と表示される

Tags: google-chrome

ヘッドレスChromeで Yahoo! JAPAN スクリーンキャプチャを取得すると、真ん中下部分が

> 記事を取得できませんでした

と表示されます。

コマンドラインで `--virtual-time-budget=10000` を指定してみたのですが結果は同じでした。

```
$ google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu \
    --screenshot --window-size=1280,1080 \
    --virtual-time-budget=10000 https://www.yahoo.co.jp
```

**Q1.何か特別なパラメーター設定が必要ですか？**
ユーザーエージェント？
クッキー？

**Q2.Yahoo! JAPAN で「記事を取得できませんでした」と表示される条件は何だと考えられますか？**

**Q3.ヘッドレスChromeではなく、通常のChromeでこの現象を再現する方法はありますか？**
この表示になる時どういうDOM構成になっているか確認できれば条件分岐できるかもと考えています

環境
CentOS7

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) が原因ではないかな、と思われます。chrome の オプションに `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir='./user-data'` を追加して実行するとニュース画像もキャプチャできる様になりました。ただ、`--user-data-dir` に指定するディレクトリ(この場合では `./user-data`)を予め作成しておくことと、コマンドを2回実行する必要がありました(1度目の実行で cross-site resource な cookie を保存する必要があるらしいです)。なお、`--virtual-time-budget` オプションは必要ありませんでした。

Comment: 月並みですが、`--user-agent`オプションを指定してみてはどうでしょう？ Windowsで試して同じ現象になったので、`--user-agent`を追加してみたら取得できました。

Comment: @metropolis。2回目で期待した通り取得できました。 /user-data/Default/Cookiesファイルを作成することで、CORSを突破するのは凄いと思いました

Comment: @kunif。情報ありがとうございました。期待した通り取得できました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「期待した通り取得できました」とのこととUp Voteがあったのでコメントを回答化しておきます。

月並みですが、`--user-agent`オプションを指定してみてはどうでしょう？ Windowsで試して同じ現象になったので、`--user-agent`を追加してみたら取得できました。
以下のような感じで。

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --user-agent --screenshot --window-size=1280,1080 --virtual-time-budget=10000 https://www.yahoo.co.jp